# Issue with powering MP3 module with Amplifier

Tags: amplifier, step-up

I'm not a electronics engineer/student, so please escuse me if my query sounds a bit naieve.

I have a Mp3+FM module ([link](https://www.amazon.in/dp/B078N7T7YH/ref=pe_3025041_189395861_pe_194751_29698841_3p_dp_1)) which I can power with a regular micro USB charger(or desktop USB). As the module cannot power a speaker I have attached a PAM8403 Class D Amp module ([link](https://www.amazon.in/dp/B074C2B7ZK/ref=pe_3025041_189395861_pe_194751_29698841_3p_dp_1)) (i think it can take from 3.5 to 5.5 V).

To make this setup mobile I added a 18650 rechargable 3.7V 2200mAH battery ([link](https://robokits.co.in/batteries-chargers/lithium-ion-battery/lithium-ion-18650-rechargeable-cell-3.7v-2200mah-2c-grade-a)) and a TP4056 1.2A 5V charging module([link](https://robokits.co.in/batteries-chargers/tp4056-1.2a-5v-li-ion-battery-charge-discharge-protection-module)). Now when I run the circuit with 5V external power attached to TP4056 it works well (thoe the volume is low and it takes few power cycles to start). But when I run it using only 
 the battery, the module just keeps cycling the power (On/off..). 
[image: Initial Setup]
(Diagram 1)

I thought as my battery is a bit underpowered and TP4056 only provides 4.2V power I can add a step-up converter. So I added MT3608 DC-DC Step Up Converter ([link](https://www.amazon.in/dp/B07FWXBMDB/ref=pe_3025041_189395861_pe_194751_29698841_3p_dp_1)) and adjusted it to 5V, 7V & 8V but none of it seem to work. Can you please let me know if I had missed anything ?
[image: Circuit with StepUp converter]

Unfortunately as I don't have any electronics background, I am not aware of how do debug (sorry for the software lingo) this issue. I do have a multimeter so I would really appreciate if anyone can point me in a right direction or jolt down some steps to do more investigation.

Update:
As requested these are the power specs of the various modules:

- **MP3**

> Input Supply: 5V;
>   S/N: 65dB;
>   Distortion: 0.2%;
>   Output: 550 mV;

- **PAM 8403**

> 3W Output at 10% THD with a 4Ω Load and 5V Power Supply;
>   Speaker With: 4~8ohms, recommended: 4ohms Speaker Power: 2~8W

- **TP 4056 Battery Charger**

> Based on TP4056 1A Standalone Linear Li-lon Battery Charger with Thermal Regulation chip;
>   Preset 4.2V Charge Voltage with 1.5% Accuracy;
>   2.9V Trickle Charge Threshold (TP4056);

- **MT3608 StepUp**

> Integrated 80mΩ Power MOSFET;
>   2V to 24V Input Voltage;
>   1.2MHz Fixed Switching Frequency;
>   Internal 4A Switch Current Limit;
>   Maximum Output Current: 2A;

Comment: 5V should be 5V – use a multimeter to verify your step up converter is actually supplying a stable 5V.

Comment: Hi Marcus, thanks for the feedback. I checked the step-up by  removing other modules (MP3 and amp) and it was providing steady 5V. I even tried to add the modules in series but the MP3 module just did not power on.

Comment: adding the modules in series will not work. That's not how boost converters work. You even stand a good change of damaging things that way.

Comment: You don't show your power connections for the amplifier or the rated output power of your step up converter, or the input power requirements of your MP3 and amplifier modules.  Add all information for their power requirements.  Your boost converter must be able to provide a solid 5V *at full load* so when you disconnect the load to measure, you confirmed only it's no load output.

Comment: If you have difficulties finding a sufficiently powerful boost converter with decent efficiency, consider adding a second 18650 and using a buck converter instead.

Comment: @MarcusMüller : Hi Marcus, thats exaclty what I did unfortunately ... and as you rightly pointed out my MP3 module is fried (semi fried .. but anyways... its not working as before) .. Thanks for sharing the info thoe... now I know which step actually caused it.

Comment: @KH : Hi KH.Thanks for the feedback. I have provided links to the actual product I have used. Unfortunately the MP3/FM module is quiet generic and does not have lot of info apart from what I have mentioned in the diagram. I have copied all the specs available in the main post, maybe that can be helpful.

Comment: @KH : Since i don't have much knowledge of electronics, can you please let me know how to measure the full load ?  For measuring the 'no load' scenario I had used multimeter and touched the leads of multimeter to the + & - of the converter. Do you want me to do the same when the complete setup is running while external power is on (because that's the only scenario in which the whole thing works, on battery alone it just keeps circling in power loop).

Comment: @KH : Also, on the point of input requirements of MP3 module, as  I mentioned in my previous comment there is no documentation available, so is there any way of measuring it via. the multi-meter, I can do that and post the details.  Again, apologies for my naive question as mentioned, i don't have background on electronics.

Comment: @KH : As requested, I've updated all the data I can find on modules as well as the second diagram (showing power connection of amplifier). Thanks again for taking time to direct me in the right path :)